# Reference material for JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Hi although this is not technical question, it is important to know where can someone find *best* from the experts.I am new in **JQuery**, I am using `http://jquery.com/` for learning purposes. But it would be appreciable if I could have some better reference learning site for JQuery where videos and demos are available

Comment: Just google for tutorials or examples. Should be pretty easy to find jQuery stuff out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So presuming you're somewhat familiar with jQuery, I would advise starting with JavaScript.

1. [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-combined) run through the whole thing and you will **understand** JavaScript
2. jQuery's official site has a long, comprehensive [list of tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials). Pick the ones you think are down your alley and run with it.

After that, there are many, many good sites dedicated to jQuery.

Some that you might like are:

- http://www.learningjquery.com/
- http://jqueryfordesigners.com/
- http://visualjquery.com/1.1.2.html (doesn't teach, just think of it as visual docs for the framework)

Comment: Thanks for listing pretty good sites for learning javascript and jquery

Comment: @eraj you are more than welcome. However, if you want to learn `advanced` topics in jQuery, my advise would be to not sit and "learn" them. Pick up a project, dream of what you want to do and then figure out how to do it and for this SO and google are the only relevant sites :)

Answer (score 1):

[The New Boston jQuery Video Tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)

This is a very good site.
I have gone through many tutorials and they are extremely helpful

Just try few videos first and see how much you get from it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, for providing me wonderful site. Can you share references for Advance functionality like JQuery AJAX, Calling web services etc.

Comment: that site has advanced functionality of ajax but don't know about web services

Answer (score 0):

http://listic.ru/jQuery_Cookbook.pdf

found this quite organised and useful.